# SQL error - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm aware that there are numerous questions similar to this that have been asked before, but I've looked through many of them and I haven't been able to find a solution to my following problem.

This is my attempt at writing a query that displays the total number of reservations by room type in the month of March:

```
 select rt.room_type_id as RoomType
      , count(r.no_of_reservations) as NoOfReservations
 from Room_type rt
    , Room r
    , Reservation res
where rt.room_type_id = r.room_type_id
  and r.room_id = res.room_id
  and extract(month from res.check_in_date) = 3
  and extract(month from res.check_out_date) = 3
order by r.no_of_reservations
group by r.room_type_id;
```

When I run this query, I get the error: `ERROR at line 11: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

How do I fix this? I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause should be the last statement

Comment: @NickKrasnov I made that change and got the error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: The sequence of writing and SQL query is. 1. SELECT 2. FROM 3. WHERE 4. GROUP BY 5. ORDER BY

Comment: Moreover wherever there is a GROUP BY clause. You should use only group functions or the column the column(s) on which you have grouped by. In your case it is rt.room_type_id instead of r.room_type_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
select r.room_type_id as RoomType       -- rt alias changed to r to match group by
      ,count(r.no_of_reservations) as NoOfReservations
from Room_type rt                        -- explicit join
join Room r
  on rt.room_type_id = r.room_type_id
join Reservation res
  on r.room_id = res.room_id
where extract(month from res.check_in_date) = 3
  and extract(month from res.check_out_date) = 3
group by r.room_type_id       --swapped lines group by <=> order by
order by NoOfReservations;    --alias from SELECT
```

Comment: Why? Didn't Oracle tell you *why* once you tried it? Because of ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. You didn't SELECT it, so you can't ORDER BY it when aggregates are contained in the statement. Similarly, when selecting DISTINCT values and ordering by a column that isn't part of the SELECT statement, you'd get ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression.